# How to access 'missing' Environmental variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, environment-variables

I am adding an environmental variable in bashrc, but am unable to see the variables using os.environ.get in a Python file.

I am using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I am setting an environmental variable in “bashrc” as follows:

```
export DB_USER='emailAddress@gmail.com'
```

When calling the following on Terminal:

```
$ env
```

…I find DB_USER in a the list of 24 items.

However, when I use the following in a Python file (this file is called by a bash script):

```
import os
...
try:
    with open("tempFile.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(os.environ))
        f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("FileNotFoundError")
except IOError:
    print("IOError")
```

then ‘DB_USER’ is not in the list of 11 entries in "tempFile.txt".

How can I access the list of 24 items so that I can use ‘DB_USER’ entry?

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the Bash script that calls the Python script? From the command line? Or some other method?

Comment: bashrc is available only in a bash environment. See [here](https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/). Therefore the question of @MattDMo. Also, check whether you start the script as normal user or via sudo.

Comment: @MattDMo - The Python script it being called by a Bash script. In turn, the Bash script is being called by a service.

Comment: @cwellm - The Bash script is being started by a service; would this be classed as being a normal user?

Comment: Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service for some possible solutions. My Pi is currently AWOL, so I can't verify if Raspbian uses `systemd`, but the google machine says it does, so the first solution in the first answer *should* work.

Comment: The service isn't inheriting *its* environment from your shell, which means Python isn't either.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your comment. The information about the service not inheriting the environment was one piece of the puzzle that I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a *service* (so, not your user, as per Chepner's comment) calling something this looks like you want to make the environment variable available system-wide.

[/etc/environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) may fit your needs.  You would just *add*

```
DB_USER=emailAddress@gmail.com
```

to it.  (no, don't use `export`)

See also https://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-environment-and-etc-profile and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37771/setting-system-wide-path-not-working-in-etc-environment (which talks about using `/etc/profile.d` instead, but similar concept - that's probably the approach I'd take, after testing a basic `/etc/environment` based fix)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
import os, subprocess

# try to simulate being the user so you can import/capture the env as that user
cmd = 'env -i sh -c ". /home/user/.bashrc && env"'

try:
    with open("tempFile.txt", "a") as f:
        for line in subprocess.getoutput(cmd).split("\n"):
        f.write(str(line))
        f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("FileNotFoundError")
except IOError:
    print("IOError")
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed to find a solution thanks to the suggestions given in this post.

I’m currently using /etc/environment in a script as follows :

```
  # get environmental variables
  source /etc/environment
  
  afile='<file path and name>‘

  date >> $afile
  
  echo >> $afile
  echo Straight from set >> $afile
  echo $DB_USER_environment >> $afile
  echo >> $afile
  
  echo Via a variable in the script >> $afile
  db_user02=$DB_USER_environment
  echo $db_user02 >> $afile
  
  echo >> $afile
```

This adds the following to `afile`

```
Sat 12 Nov 11:56:11 GMT 2022

Straight from set
emailAddress@gmail.com

Via a variable in the script
emailAddress@gmail.com
```

I intend to look at the etc/profile.d (@JL Peyret), Python (@TheAnalogyGuy) and systemd (@MattDMo) suggestions.

Thanks for all the replies